# WPF control inside Winforms doesn't work?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have a winforms application, I wanted to add a WPF checkbox to this application, so I followed these steps :

1- Right click on the project name, then choose **Add->User Control**
2- I choose **User Control (WPF)** from the list
 3- I add a check box to the WPF designer

4- I Build the application

The question : After adding an **ElementHost** to my Winforms App, and expand the Child property, I don't see any controls, There is only a message saying **(Add a new or existing WPF control to begin)**

What I'm doing wrong ?

**Edit :** I have also tried to add a reference to **WindowsFormsIntegration** but results are same

Comment: I have tried this out using both VS2010 (.net 3.5) and VS2012 (.net 4.5). Did you build, or Rebuild...? I found that it didn't always find the WPF user control unless I specifically Re-built the project.

Comment: I think there is a problem with my VS 2012 because i tested it in 2010 and it worked correctly. The problem is with Visual 2012 only.

Answer (score 0):

When you build the WPF user control, the control will be listed in the Toolbox. Drag the control to the element host.